# powershell - Get-Credential PScredential object is different from New-Object -TypeName "System.Management.Automation.PSCredential"

Tags: powershell

I am invoking a web api which uses ntlm authentication from PowerShell.
Script gets user credentials using get-credential. it works fine. code is below.

```
$cred_getcred_approach= get-credential
$response = Invoke-RestMethod $uri -Method 'POST' -Headers $headers -Body $body -Credential $cred_getcred_approach
```

to avoid the credential prompt I created a PSCredential object with same userid & password(that I filled in the get-credential prompt)

```
$User = "Domain01\User01"
$PWord = ConvertTo-SecureString -String "P@sSwOrd" -AsPlainText -Force
$cred_createcred_approach = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $User, $PWord
```

Authentication fails in this case. Surprised with this behavior, I exported both PSCredential objects to an xml file using below code.

```
$cred_getcred_approach | Export-CliXml -Path "c:\path\cred_getcred_approach.xml" 
$cred_createcred_approach | Export-CliXml -Path "c:\path\cred_createcred_approach.xml"
```

and the password value doesn't match between these 2 xml files.  I tried to import the xml files and invoke the web api.

```
$cred_getcred_approach= Import-CliXml -Path "c:\path\cred_getcred_approach.xml" 
$cred_createcred_approach= Import-CliXml -Path "c:\path\cred_createcred_approach.xml"
```

As expected, the authentication was successful when I imported in the first case.(from the xml(cred_getcred_approach.xml) which was exported from the get-credential PSCredential  object and failed on other case. What can be the reason? is there any difference in the secure string algorithms? Is there any ways to fix this?

**Update**

secured string was problematic. below code fixed it.

```
$pass = ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText "P@sSwOrd" -Force
```

I got the original problematic code one from the [microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.security/get-credential?view=powershell-7#example-7). below is that problematic code.

```
$pass = ConvertTo-SecureString -String "P@sSwOrd" -AsPlainText -Force
```

Thanks to @tomalak for the pointer.

Comment: You can use `Invoke-WebRequest -UseDefaultCredentials` to use integrated authentication, i.e. to use the credential of the account running the script. This way you don't have to rely on obtaining or saving any explicit credentials at all.

Comment: >use the credential of the account running the script< this script is going to be run by rundeck/chef. that account necessarily don't have access to the web api. i have to supply the credential explicitly. but unable to create it from clear password other than relying on the get-credential prompt

Comment: as i mentioned in the post, in my case there is a difference in the pscredential object created by "get-credential" method and the pscredential objected created using secure string created from the plain text string. can you read the post again ?

Comment: thank you tomalk for the pointer. i updated the post

Comment: Can you post that as an answer instead of as an update to your question? This way I can upvote and you can click "accepted answer & close the thread (and maybe somebody else finds it some day and it helps them)

Answer (score 0):

secured string was problematic. below code fixed it.

```
$pass = ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText "P@sSwOrd" -Force
```

I got the original problematic code one from the [microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.security/get-credential?view=powershell-7#example-7). below is that problematic code.

```
$pass = ConvertTo-SecureString -String "P@sSwOrd" -AsPlainText -Force
```

Thanks to @tomalak for the pointer.